# How to Disable ui.button in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button, ui

This may be broader question on how we set HTML attributes inside Lightning?
The docs state ui:button has disabled property and it works fine in VFP for all VF components. But how do I set this attribute inside Lightning JS Controller?
Nothing seem to work try several options in component controller JS;
...

```
var btn = event.getSource();
btn.disabled = true;
btn.disabled.set(true);
btn.attributes.disabled = true;
```

... many others but cannot effect the button state to set disabled on click event.
No syntax errors (figure no compiled code JS) just not working.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The right syntax to do this is below

```
var btn = event.getSource();
btn.set("v.disabled",true);//Disable the button
```

Answer (score 0):

More one trick... if input field don't return to enable with disabled = false use disabled = ""

```
btn.set("v.disabled",""); //but this don't function with toggle, function with select that i tested

btn.set("v.disabled","false"); //this in input select for sample don't function.
```